# How I concat 2 int columns ms-access

Tags: ms-access

How I concat 2 int columns.
I need concat this columns

Column 1: 3030

Column 2: 1245963

`Result: 3030-1245963`

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+access+concatenate+fields&oq=ms+access+concatenate+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.10571j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select column1 & "-" & column2 as yourfield from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a query, you can create a new field from an existing table with:

```
Newvalue: CStr([field1]) & "-" & CStr([field2])
```

[image: Query Code]

[image: Result]